# Show a custom selection pop-up for TextView as Google Play Books does?

Tags: android, textview, android-widget, android-custom-view, android-menu

This is not adding a custom menu item, but using a different UI structure for the text selection menu of `TextView`. Something like Google Play Book does (screenshot below). How can one do that?

`TextView` has `customSelectionActionModeCallback` but it seems that there is not much I can do by setting a `ActionMode.Callback`. One stupid way I can think of is returning `false` in `onCreateActionMode` to prevent the selection menu from the system, and show a completely independent some sort of pop-up myself. Is that the way how Google Play Book does that?

[image]

Comment: Is that triggered via a long click? If so, perhaps [register a long-click listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#setonlongclicklistener).